# ViewState object lost in Master Page Load

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, viewstate

I am assigning ViewState["something"] in Page Load of content page and when I try to access the ViewState variable in Master Page Load event handler, the viewstate variable is lost.Can anyone guide me why this is happening and the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Master pages and content pages do not share the same ViewState.
If you are trying to pass something from the content page to the master page there are a couple of alternatives:
- use this.Context.Items that is common to the entire site during an HTTP request
- make a public property on the master page, cast this.Master from the content page to the master page class and set the property
- use Session

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (just found it on the web) this is a hint to the solution:

> Unless the MasterPage has its ViewState turned on, all controls below it would lose their state.

Found this in a blog post titled [MasterPage and viewstate issue](https://web.archive.org/web/20161212011915/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/vivek/archive/2006/10/04/93094.aspx). Could it have something to do with the Viewstate being turned off in the master page?

Comment: I am using a viewstate object declaratively in code. aslo checked that view state of my master page is turned on...