# Something like viewstate and session

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, master-pages, viewstate

The problem that I am having is as follows:

I currently have a custom class that generates buttons and places them on a placeholder on a master page.

The events for these buttons put specific values into session that differs values for a database query. In essence, the buttons serve as filters for charts.

After creating all the buttons, I realized that session values will stay constant from page to page, so everytime a user enters a different page while another is open, the filters selected on the open page will remain constant for the new page that is opened.

At first, I wanted to use viewstate rather than session, but then realized that a master page and a content page do not share the same viewstate.

At the current time, I am thinking of using a prefix for the sesson key that will identify what page the filters actually exist for. However, I am not wanting to overload session with numerous values if the user wishes to have many pages open at the same time.

Any solutions that would entail a way to share viewstate (or some other way to store values) between app_code, the master, and the content page?

Comment: So, what you are saying is that when you redirect to a new page, you want the have the filters with default values and not the values from the previous page?

Comment: I'm another developer on this project.  Part of the problem is the system we're using to display various charts has four screens.  Each screen (with one browser instance) needs to be able to keep track of what it is filtering different from each of the others.  Hence our inital use of viewstate.  Session is just one instance, so when you update one browser, it's using all the filters from the most recent change on any of the other instances.

Comment: How long are the filter values and how many are there? Have you considered the URL query?

Comment: The filter values themselves are not too long. However, there are probably around ten different types of filters, which is not constant across the pages. The number of filters displayed on the page is set via a property in the masterpage.

The URL solution does have a few appealing aspects, mainly the fact that a user could bookmark a preset filter selection. Yet, the main disadvantage is that the user would be able to see the different parameters for the filters (Database attacks), and the possible length of the ten different filters existing in the query.

Comment: Josh,

How are you adding the filter parameters to the query string? Is there a way to do it without manually redirecting the page?

Comment: You don't have to put the actual column names in the query, just pseudo names. As for the manual redirect, I'm not sure what you mean. I do it in javascript, I pop up a dialog, say for daterange, and when the user enters the values, I append them to the query using the JQuery plugin that I mentioned, which makes modifying, removing, and adding query parameters, childs play.

Answer (score 1):

Use HttpContext.Current.Items, it is a key-value pair collection with a lifetime of a single Http Request.

Comment: This sounds like the right direction for my problem.

However, since it only has a lifetime for a single request, would the user be able to select multiple filters and have those values persist across the different selections?

Comment: In the case of multiple pages, hence multiple Http Request, no, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Context.Items](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

How many filters are we talking here? Store the filter values in the URL. Have you seen some of the URLs that google or an ecommerce site uses? They are quite long. Here is how I do it:

1. I store the filter values in the query like, www.chart.com?filter1=val1&filter2=val2 etc.
2. I user [JQuery's query plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) to manipulate the query on the client side, and then request the chart from the server again, using the new query.
3. This way, I'm not junking up session, cookies, or anything like that, and if the user wants to store a bookmark to a particular chart or email it to a friend, they can and the filters are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting to think the answer shown in the following question will work:

[ViewState object lost in Master Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378381/viewstate-object-lost-in-master-page-load)

Exposing the desired variables via a property.

Answer (score 0):

If the data isn't too long, cookies are a typical solution.

Another option is to use Silverlight isolated storage.  The Silverlight control itself could be invisible (no UI).